# How to umount nfs (stale filehandle) on ancient XenServer kernel without reboot?

Tags: nfs, xenserver

It's particularly hard to find a solution to this problem, due to the fact that most resources online preach `umount -f` or `umount -l` (or `umount -fl`) approach. In my case, it doesn't work.

```
# uname -a
Linux nanoxen 3.10.0+2 #1 SMP Wed Mar 11 11:20:46 EDT 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
# lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: XenServer
Description:    XenServer release 6.5.0-90233c (xenenterprise)
Release:    6.5.0-90233c
Codename:   xenenterprise
# cat /proc/fs/nfsfs/volumes
NV SERVER   PORT DEV     FSID              FSC
v3 c0a8035e  801 0:21    e4a6f662369dc558  no 
v3 c0a80726  801 0:20    bb4ff13aad86bb0e  no 
v3 c0a8023f  801 0:22    e4a6f662369dc558  no 
# umount -fl /var/run/sr-mount/589b5772-0c84-45df-af71-4882160b64d7
umount: /var/run/sr-mount/589b5772-0c84-45df-af71-4882160b64d7: Stale NFS file handle
```

As far as I understand, `stale filehandle` issues arise when filesystem id changes. So I hoped that I can craft a correct response to NFS client, response that contains a correct filesystem id. I attempted to do it but got lost in scapy code.

I also discovered that one can specify arbitrary fsid in /etc/exports file on NFS server. But I still cannot create an export with matching fsid! Manual says fsid in /etc/exports should be 32 hex numbers or small int. The number I got from /proc/fs/nfsfs/volumes is 16 hex numbers, so it's too short. Converting it to int also doesn't work.

EDIT:

```
# grep /var/run/sr-mount/589b5772-0c84-45df-af71-4882160b64d7 /proc/mounts 
share1:/mnt/iso/export /var/run/sr-mount/589b5772-0c84-45df-af71-4882160b64d7 nfs rw,relatime,vers=3,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,port=2049,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,local_lock=none,addr=192.168.3.94 0 0
```

Comment: Add up output of the cmd *mount*. To do just run **mount** as *root*.

Comment: @jluizsouzadev `mount` doesn't report much on this system, I added part of `/proc/mounts` to the question